# Size difference for hdfs folder

Tags: azure, hadoop, hdfs, blob, azure-hdinsight

I have executed the following hdfs commands.
Both are basically same which gives the total size of the folder in GB.
The -du -h -s command lists the file size in MB or in KB , so I am doing the necessary conversion.
But I can see a size difference.
any idea why is it like that?.

```
hdfs dfs -du -h -s /Dataproviders/DataSurgery/input/KAI/Order/Ready/KAI_Order*.* | awk -F' ' 'BEGIN{SUM=0}{ if($2=="M"){SUM+=$1} else if($2=="K"){SUM = SUM + ($1/1024)} } END{ SUM=SUM/1024; print SUM  }'
```

10.1268

```
hdfs dfs -du -h -s /Dataproviders/DataSurgery/input/KAI/Order/Ready/
```

12.9 GB

Comment: does the second command gives internal memory reserved or used by the spark framework..something of that sort?

Comment: In the first command you calculate the size using glob filter for files: KAI_Order*.*; In the second command you calculate the total size of the folder. May be there are some more files which are not included by KAI_Order*.* filter?